# IO exception inside static class - java

Tags: java, exception, hadoop, ioexception

```
public class classifyTweet {

  public static class MapClass 
          extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

  static final Configuration conf = new Configuration();

  protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) 
             throws IOException, InterruptedException {

  StandardNaiveBayesClassifier classifier = new StandardNaiveBayesClassifier(NaiveBayesModel.materialize(new Path(modelPath), conf));

    }
  }
 }
```

I want to initialize the classifier variable only once, materialize method is throwing IOEception, if I declare it outside map method and like configuration object initialization it gives compilation error of IOException. How can I initialize it only once?

Comment: Provide the stack trace of that exception.

Comment: getting error at compilation.. unreported IOException must be caught or thrown

Answer (score 1):

make StandardNaiveBayesClassifier - singleton

```
public class StandardNaiveBayesClassifier {
private static StandardNaiveBayesClassifier instance;

public static StandardNaiveBayesClassifier getInstance(... you params) {
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new StandardNaiveBayesClassifier();
    return instance;
}

private StandardNaiveBayesClassifier() {
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use a static block to initialize the `classifier` variable just once.

```
public class classifyTweet {

  public static class MapClass 
          extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

  static final Configuration conf = new Configuration();

  static final StandardNaiveBayesClassifier classifier;

  static {
      try {
       classifier = new StandardNaiveBayesClassifier(NaiveBayesModel.materialize(new Path(modelPath), conf));
      }
      catch(IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          System.out.println("Initialization failed.");
      }
  }

  protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) 
             throws IOException, InterruptedException {

  //do some work...

    }
  }
 }
```

I'm assuming the `modelPath` variable is in scope when creating the `classifier` object in the static block. You don't say anything about it.

Comment: Didn't work getting same IOException, I guess because `NaiveBayesModel.materialize(new Path(modelPath), conf)` is throwing IOException I have to catch it or use throws, so is this statement have to be inside a non static method?

Comment: @MahenderSingh Yes. Indeed. I forgot to place the `try/catch` in the static block. Updated the answer.